# set system time without password

Tags: sudoers

I have a (generally) off-network machine that has time info streaming through serial from GPS.  I've captured that info and I'm trying to automatically update my system time using `sudo timedatectl set-time` and it keeps asking me for a password (I don't want to use the password).  I've gathered that I'm supposed to be updating the sudoers file, but I'm figuring that my formatting is wrong. here's what I have and it still asks me for the password. I appreciate any feedback.

```
# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
yellowfin ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/timedatectl
```

Comment: @Bravo - The comment in question, is generated from user reviews, if a user thought the question was unclear then they were probably justified in doing so. The problem is sort of clear, the author probably wants to avoid the password prompt, but that is never specifically stated. It's pointless to complain about the community bot, submitting that particular comment, since it's generated by a human reviewer.

Comment: I forgot, humour is not allowed on stackexchange sites

Answer (score 0):

The /etc/sudoers file only affects commands **that are being run through `sudo`.** If timedatectl is not being run through 'sudo', it shows a different password prompt (from polkit aka PolicyKit) that has nothing to do with /etc/sudoers.

Either run `sudo timedatectl` to make use of the added rule, or edit `/etc/polkit-1/rules.d/` to allow the time change through the [polkit](https://gist.github.com/grawity/3886114) mechanism.

But if you're looking for any kind of accuracy, you'll probably want something more direct than a D-Bus call that timedatectl makes (after several backend calls at that) – it would be better to adjust the system time using `/usr/bin/date --set` instead.

(It would be *even better* to use the built-in GPS receiver support in `chrony` or `ntpd`.)

Comment: thanks for the answer, I've updated to include the fact that I'm using (and intending to use) `sudo timedatectl XXX`.  it still doesn't work. 
 If the /usr/bin/date is more efficient for setting.  My accuracy requirements are within a second or two (i'm getting drifts >10 min).